# C++ Source code organization - COM port initialization

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

I have a program that will be communicating with multiple COM ports. As of now I have all the code in one file and it is semi messy. How could I organize it in a way where all the serial connections and connection parameters are set up somewhere else allowing me to just read or write to the port in the main file.

Here is an example of configuration I mean

```
HANDLE hSerial = CreateFile("COM3",GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);


DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
dcbSerialParams.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;
```

Comment: how about putting all code you posted in a function accepting a string and returning a handle? or else make a class representing a com port..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HANDLE hSerial = CreateFile("COM3",GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,.......`

The only thing that is unique to each com port is the name "com3" so this is all you need to supply to the function.  The handle returned by Createfile completely identifies the open port, it's the only thing you need to read/write the port and close it when you have finished.

So learn about functions and pass in the name of the port and return the handle

Answer (score 0):

Define a 'T_COMport' class in another module. Add sufficient constructor parameters to set up the port, together with read/write methods, the _DCB struct, all those nasty, annoying serial port setup calls and any threads or other stuff necessary to make the port work as you need.  Maybe an event or two for rx data or whatever.  Put the templates in a header file as usual, include it in your main app, as usual.

The just create an instance for each port and start reading/writing stuff.

Rgds,
Martin